# ETag changing on every request. Rack middleware interfering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rack, etag

In a small quest to improve caching in my Rails (3.2) application, I noticed that my Etag header changes for every single request.

I suppose this is because some part of my middleware is changing the response contents on every request, but I don't understand what. This is the result of running `rake middleware`:

```
use Rack::Cache
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x007f462e790e98>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use ActionDispatch::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::Deflater
use Rack::ETag
use ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
use Warden::Manager
use Rack::Attack
use Rack::SslEnforcer
use HireFire::Middleware`
```

After some research I stumbled upon some information that Rack::Deflater is generating a timestamp for everything it deflates. I've tried moving Rack::Deflater after Rack::ETag (`config.middleware.insert_after Rack::ETag, Rack::Deflater`), but the ETag header *still* changes on every request.

Anyone here with more rack experience who could help me find out what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Well, let's start with the following. `ETag` should be before `Deflater`. That's for sure. You can try to hook up into ETag middleware itself with debugger, and try to analyze content it receives. Couple of requests, and you will find dynamic part of it.

Comment: Are you positive that `ETag` should be before `Deflater`? If I insert `Deflater` after `ETag` then the body object used for calculating the digest is a `Rack::Deflater::GzipStream` with timestamp and all. If I do the other way round, the body object is a `ActionDispatch::Response` which seems to be the same every time, at least in development.

Comment: Just to ensure what we understand each other correctly, by `before` I mean that `ETag` should be processed ***before*** `Deflater` by the reasons you stated above. `ActionDispath::Response` seems to be the same every time? Assuming that `ETag` is calculated based on response body, you need to hook to that process and check that for sure. I will put some details in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a relevant source code of `Rack::ETag`:

```
def call(env)
  status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

  if etag_status?(status) && etag_body?(body) && !skip_caching?(headers)
    original_body = body
    digest, new_body = digest_body(body)
    body = Rack::BodyProxy.new(new_body) do
      original_body.close if original_body.respond_to?(:close)
    end
    headers['ETag'] = %("#{digest}") if digest
  end

  unless headers['Cache-Control']
    if digest
      headers['Cache-Control'] = @cache_control if @cache_control
    else
      headers['Cache-Control'] = @no_cache_control if @no_cache_control
    end
  end

  [status, headers, body]
end
```

As you can see, digest is calculated based on response body (using `digest_body`). Here's the source:

```
def digest_body(body)
  parts = []
  digest = nil

  body.each do |part|
    parts << part
    (digest ||= Digest::MD5.new) << part unless part.empty?
  end

  [digest && digest.hexdigest, parts]
end
```

You can hook inside of that method. I believe you will find that there's something dynamic in your response and this blocks you from using `ETag` header. For example, there maybe CSRF protection tokens in your forms, or something like that. I would strongly suggest you to use something like [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) for placing breakpoints.

Comment: Indeed I have found something lurking around: The New Relic middleware, which inserts timing information in each response. Your answer got me digging deeper into the source code and I stumbled upon this. Thanks!